# Cloudstack client installation

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have XAMPP installed on Windows 10. And have successfully installed Composer, Laravel. I can see the basic Laravel project page on my local server.
Just to try things out I also installed yii2. I can see the basic yii2 page also on my local server.

Now I'm trying to install this Generic Cloudstack Client:
https://github.com/PCextreme/cloudstack-client

In XAMPP, under htdocs I have this dir called 'LaravelProjects'.

[dir structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WayXM.png)

First I made the project with the laravel command:

```
laravel new PCextreme
```

Then in PCextreme directory I give the command:

```
composer require pcextreme/cloudstack-client:~0.1
```

The composer breaks and shows Conclusion: remove laravel/framework 5.2.41

But in the instructions there is another method to install the package.
When I do that by editting the composer.json in the main Laravel dir. 'LaravelProjects' under xampp/htdocs with these lines:

```
"require": { "pcextreme/cloudstack-client": "~0.1" }
```

And then I run the "composer update" command.

I don't get any error.

But as soon as I follow these steps:

> Once the package is installed you need to open app/config/app.php and register the required service provider:

```
`'providers' => [
'PCextreme\CloudstackClient\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider']`
```

The application breaks.
I can't see the basic page showing 'Laravel 5' on my server anymore.
Instead of that I get a fatal error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146: Class

'PCextreme\CloudstackClient\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider' not found
```

Further in the instructions, when I give the command below:

```
php artisan config:publish pcextreme/cloudstack-client
```

I get this error:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'PCextreme\CloudstackClient\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider' not found
```

I have tried out different things that I could find on internet but nothing seems to work in my case.

Could someone kindly help me out with this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Execute in you project folder command: `composer update`

Comment: Yes I have. And also 'composer dump-autoload'.

Comment: Do you run this: `composer require pcextreme/cloudstack-client:~0.1` ?

Comment: But I also tried with, ""require": {
    "pcextreme/cloudstack-client": "~0.1"
}" And after that I ran "composer update" cmmand.

Comment: After fresh installation `laravel new testproject` i run command: `composer require pcextreme/cloudstack-client:~0.1` and composer breaks and show error and write conclusion `Conclusion: remove laravel/framework 5.2.41` so maby this library is just too old or broken to new laravel 5.2. May be try to find some other library

Comment: I tried with, 'pcextreme/cloudstack-client:~0.1.7' Then the composer doesn't break. But later on I get the error.

Comment: I have MacOs elCapitan, and run `composer require pcextreme/cloudstack-client:~0.1.7` and get the same error (remove laravel...)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer, it seems to be asking for clarification, and therefore should be a comment.

Comment: Did you try with, "require": {
    "pcextreme/cloudstack-client": "~0.1.7"
} and then composer update?

Comment: i try this too, the same result (composer breaks). Can you check your vendor directory? Do you see this library there?

Comment: That's essentially the same exact command.  `~0.1` will grab the latest up until before the next major version `1.0` which in this case is `0.1.7`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Yes I see it under my the xampp\htdocs dir '\vendor\pcextreme\cloudstack-client'. However I did a reinstall with "require": { "pcextreme/cloudstack-client": "~0.1" } and then "composer update". It didn't break. But I still get the same error.